# How can I programmatically update componenets of Visual Studios such as NuGet?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I am aware that I can do the below:

`& "$home\Downloads\vs_Community.exe" install --productID "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community"`

However, anytime I attempt to update NuGet or Dot Net using the same method etc I receive the error "A product matching the following parameters cannot be found: "

Is there no way to achieve updating NuGet similar to the below(which fails)?

`& "$home\Downloads\vs_Community.exe" update --productID "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet"`

Updating NuGet using the below does not work as NuGet was installed using VisualStudio

`.\nuget.exe update -self`

I'm looking to update Dot Net etc as well but I am unsure of how to update components of Visual Studios from the command line atm. Thank you!

I believe the below may be what I'm looking for but I am not sure if it will update to the newest version:

`& "$home\Downloads\vs_Community.exe" update --add "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet"`

Comment: You should update all of visual studio

Answer (score 0):

NuGet cannot update individually. You can try to update visual studio use this command:

```
& "$home\Downloads\vs_Community.exe" update --passive --norestart --installpath "the path of visual studio"
```

Change your own path in the command. [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#install-update-modify-repair-uninstall-and-export-commands-and-command-line-parameters) can give some suggestion about the parameters.